# Use a state property inside the prepare callback (Redux Toolkit)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, state-management

I have a store with this `initialState`:

```js
const initialState = {
 todos : [] // [{ task: "todo something", description: "have todo something" },  ...] 
 maxTodos: 5
 ....
}
```

I want inside the `prepare` callback to `id` new todo that I will add, based on the length of the current `todos` array.

```js
reducers: {
  addTodo: {
    reducer: (state, action) => {
      return { ...state, todos: [...state.todos, action.payload]}
    },
    prepare: (state, text) => {
      const id = state.todos?.length; // the error is some what here
      return { payload: { id, text } }
    },
  },
....
```

Is there a way to access `state` inside the `prepare` callback to the slice state?

Or a different approach that can solve this?

---

The easy solution to send from the `dispatch` the length of the todo's or the create a `nanoId()` inside the `prepare`.

For now I don't want to implement this approach (written above), I want to send via the `dispatch` only the new todo that I want to add, and the id will be transparent to the `dispatch` because I want to control the todo's via their position in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prepare` function is used to preprocess the action object prior to the reducer function receiving it. It's a way to write action creators that take more than a single argument, or to add meta data to the action object.

I don't see much of a use case here for adding an `id` property that is the length of the array in state from the `prepare` function. The `prepare` function just doesn't have access to the state object. My suggestion would be to just compute the `id` in the reducer function where the state ***is*** accessible.

Example:

```js
reducers: {
  addTodo: (state, action) => {
    state.todos.push({
      text: action.payload,
      id: state.todos.length,
    })
  },
...
```

This would possibly be a bit silly, but if you really just wanted an action creator that returned a `payload` with the `text` and a generated `id` property based on the current state you could use `createAsyncThunk` and access `getState` from the `ThunkAPI`.

Example:

```js
const addTodo = createAsyncThunk(
  "todos/addTodo",
  (text, { getState }) => ({
    text,
    id: getState().todos.length, // *
  })
);

const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todos",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(addTodo.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.todos.push(action.payload);
    });
  },
});
```

****Note:** Edit to select correct state based on how the reducers are combined to form the root reducer passed to the store configurator.*